# I start system then automatically power off (15 seconds) in windows 7,

Tags: windows-7

I start the system then automatically power off (15 seconds) in windows 7.

1. Replace the ram.
2. Replace the smps.
3. Replace the hard disk.

but the same problem is occured.

Comment: Try boot from a Windows DVD or bootable USB Key, does your computer still shut down after 15 seconds?

Comment: Does it actually boot into Windows in that 15 seconds or is Windows still trying to load when it shuts down?

Comment: Have you tried Safe mode?

Answer (score 1):

If it's not any of those three, then it's probably:

1. processor overheating - usually happens when the heatsink compound has aged, or the heatsink has loosened, or the fan doesn't work properly. In this case, the processor is shut down to prevent damage to it.
2. Motherboard - It's better to send the motherboard for repairs in this case.

Also, have you checked if the same problem occurs while you're in the BIOS?